# How to get the rotation of a square Polygon?

Tags: postgis

I've got a layer made of perfect square polygons. I would like to obtain the rotation of each polygon:

[image]

In this case, the rotation would be 45 degrees.

I suppose I would have to compare it with a 0 rotation polygon, which has all of its sides parallel to the X axis or the Y axis. Example:

[image]

Comment: Take two first vertices of the polygons and use http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Azimuth.html. Depending on the location of the first vertex you may get 45, 135, 225, or 315 degrees but you do not need much mathematics for handling that case. If polygon rotates in opposite direction the angle can also be negative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with @user30184... and here is the code:

```
WITH poly AS (SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(75.15 29.53,77 29,77.6 29.5, 75.15 29.53)')) as geom)

SELECT degrees(ST_Azimuth(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom),1),ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom),3))) as degAz
FROM poly;
```

I would also add the obvious, that this solution would work decently for a somewhat square or rectangular polygon as in the example but not for more complex polygons.

In that case, perhaps this code could be used for more complex polygons which gets the azimuth from the first point to the center of the polygon:

```
WITH poly AS (SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(75.15 29.53,77 29,77.6 29.5, 75.15 29.53)')) as geom)

SELECT degrees(ST_Azimuth(st_centroid(geom),ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom),1))) as degAz
FROM poly;
```

Comment: you can also use the postgresql degrees(...) function to do the radians-to-degrees conversion